# Is this possible in python with pandas or xlwt

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an existing excel. That looks like

[image]

and I have another excel that has around 40000 rows and around 300 columns. shortened version looks like

[image]

I would like to append values to my existing excel from second excel. But only values that match values in col4 from my existing excel. So i would get something like this

[image]

Hope you guys get the picture of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Of  course it's possible. Have you had a stab at it yourself? How did it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, that is possible in pandas and it is way faster than anything in excel

```
df_result = pd.merge(FirstTable, SecondTable, how='left', on='col4')
```

this will look into both the tables for column "col4" so it needs to be named this way in both the tables.
Also be aware of the fact that if you have multiple values in second table for single value in the first table it will make as many lines in the result as in the second table.

to read the excel you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
xl=pd.ExcelFile('MyFile.xlsx')
FirstTable = pd.read_excel(xl, 'sheet_name_FIRST_TABLE')
```

for more detailed description see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging)

Comment: Thank you so much worked like a charm :) Thanks for the detailed description documentation.